# I only get a blank plane, no sign of linear equation. what's the problem here?

Tags: plotting

Try to plot this graph.

`A = {2 x + 2 y == 8, 5 x + 3 y == 15, x == 0, y == 0};
ContourPlot[A, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}]`

I only get  a blank plane,  no sign of these 2 linear equations.

Comment: [`ContourPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot) holds its first argument, so use ``ContourPlot[Evaluate @ A, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}]``.

Comment: Thank you. Carl Woll. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: You could always do `With[{A = {2 x + 2 y == 8, 5 x + 3 y == 15, x == 0, y == 0}}, ContourPlot[A, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an addition to @CarlWoll's comment :

The conditions `x==0,y==0` aren't shown because they lie on the border of the plotting range. Try

```
ContourPlot[ Evaluate@A, {x, -.1 , 5}, {y, -.1 , 5}, PlotRange -> All ]
```

[image]

to show all 4 contours.